# How to show a custom user control from a Class Library in C#

Tags: c#, events

I'm pretty new to programming with `Class Libraries` and I think my question is kind of complicated.

I'm working on my own exception logger. This exception logger has `static` routines and functions so I don't have to declare it in each of my other classes. (Is this btw a good idea? :/ ) Whenever something goes wrong, a routine is called in the exception logger class. This routine determines what the error message should be based on the number I passed to it.

My goal is as follow:

The exception logger should trigger an event in the GUI. The event in the GUI then shows a custom made message box with the error message in it. I know the possibility of declaring the exception logger in the GUI with `WithEvents`, but the there is no purpose of having everything static in the exception logger class.

---

EDIT 1: I'm looking for a way to trigger an event in the GUI project from a `ExceptionLogger` Class in a `Class Library` in the same solution without declaring the Class ExceptionLogger in every Class in my GUI project.

---

EDIT 2: Let me give an example. I have a `Class Library` named `Base`. This Class Library contains a `Class` named `ExceptionLogger`. This Class in its turn has a `Static Routine` called `Log`.

So I have a `.dll` named Base as a `Reference` in my main `Project` called `GUI`. GUI has a `Form` `MainWindow` and 2 `Classes` named `Product` and `Customer`.

What I want is that, for example, the class Customer runs into an `Error` (by using `Try...Catch`) and in the Catch part `Base.Log(1)`. The `Log` routine in `ExceptionLogger` will look up what the error message has to be and will fire an event in the GUI's `MainWindow` showing a `User Made MessageBox`.

The real question is, how do I fire this event from `Log` into the `MainWindow`?

---

EDIT 3: The `User Made MessageBox` in *EDIT 2* is rather a `Panel` that overlays the `MainWindow`, not a MessageBox window that opens.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What exactly is your problem? Getting the events around, the actual showing of the control (MessageBox?)

Comment: I'm looking for a way to trigger an event in the GUI project from a `ExceptionLogger` Class in a `Class Library` in the same solution without declaring the Class ExceptionLogger in every Class in my GUI project. Hope this clears things up?

Comment: Why do you need to register it in every control? What is your purpose with it?

Comment: added some more information in the post (EDIT 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution on my own. Any remarks are welcome. Already tnx to the ppl who commented or posted an answer.

This is an example of what I was looking for and it's working.

This is my DLL (namespace Base):

```
public class ExceptionHandler
{
    public static event EventHandler ShowErrorMessage;

    public static void test(EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowErrorMessage("me", e);
    }
}
```

This is the code in my `MainWindow`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Base.ExceptionHandler.ShowErrorMessage += ExceptionHandler_ShowErrorMessage;
    }

    void ExceptionHandler_ShowErrorMessage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((string)sender);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Base.ExceptionHandler.test(new EventArgs());
    }
}
```